# error in MATLAB imread() command

Tags: ssh, matlab, locale

Whenever I try to execute `imread('example.jpg')` in MATLAB 2014b, I got an exception:

```
Caught "std::exception" Exception message is:
locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
```

I get it also when initiating Matlab. It is installed on a remote desktop where I connect via SSH

I tried to change the locale file several times, but it did not work out. My current `/etc/defaults/locale` looks like

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=fi_FI.UTF-8
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=C
```

But when I run locale command I got

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=C
```

Does that mismatch cause the problem? How to get rid of that exception?

Comment: I would remove the `LC_ALL=C` line from `/etc/default/locale`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried it, but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve it by simply adding

```
setenv('LC_ALL','C')
```

to the Matlab code.